# Pass in an enum as a method parameter

Tags: c#, enums

I have declared an enum:

```
public enum SupportedPermissions
{
    basic,
    repository,
    both
}
```

I also have a POCO like this:

```
public class File
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public SupportedPermissions SupportedPermissions { get; set; }      
}
```

Now I would like to create a method that I can use to create a new File object with:

```
public string CreateFile(string id, string name, string description, Enum supportedPermissions)
{
    file = new File
    {  
        Name = name,
        Id = id,
        Description = description,
        SupportedPermissions = supportedPermissions.basic
    };

    return file.Id;
}
```

How would I create the parameter for the enum and how would I assign that like in my pseudo code `SupportedPermissions = supportedPermissions.basic` so that my File instance has a SupportedPermissions set to it?

Comment: Is this a bad question? Reason for down voting?

Comment: pass SupportedPermissions.basic in parameters while calling the method n set the variable supportedPermissions to the property. Hope it helps

Comment: Reason for downvote is naming Variable like Enum.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Change the signature of the `CreateFile` method to expect a `SupportedPermissions` value instead of plain Enum.

```
public string CreateFile(string id, string name, string description, SupportedPermissions supportedPermissions)
{
    file = new File
    {  
        Name = name,
        Id = id,
        Description = description,
        SupportedPermissions = supportedPermissions
    };

    return file.Id;
}
```

Then when you call your method you pass the `SupportedPermissions` value to your method

```
  var basicFile = CreateFile(myId, myName, myDescription, SupportedPermissions.basic);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to pass in the value to use, you have to use the enum type you declared and directly use the supplied value:

```
public string CreateFile(string id, string name, string description,
              /* --> */  SupportedPermissions supportedPermissions)
{
    file = new File
    {  
        Name = name,
        Id = id,
        Description = description,
        SupportedPermissions = supportedPermissions // <---
    };

    return file.Id;
}
```

If you instead want to use a fixed value, you don't need any parameter at all. Instead, directly use the enum value. The syntax is similar to a static member of a class:

```
public string CreateFile(string id, string name, string description) // <---
{
    file = new File
    {  
        Name = name,
        Id = id,
        Description = description,
        SupportedPermissions = SupportedPermissions.basic // <---
    };

    return file.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First change the method parameter `Enum supportedPermissions` to `SupportedPermissions supportedPermissions`.

Then create your file like this

```
file = new File
{  
    Name = name,
    Id = id,
    Description = description,
    SupportedPermissions = supportedPermissions
};
```

And the call to your method should be

```
CreateFile(id, name, description, SupportedPermissions.basic);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string CreateFile(string id, string name, string description, SupportedPermissions supportedPermissions)
{
    file = new File
    {  
       Name = name,
        Id = id,
        Description = description,
        SupportedPermissions = supportedPermissions
    };

    return file.Id;
}
```