# Can I use ENUM as a parameter? C#

Tags: enums

I have enum code here.

```
    public enum SCode
    {
        F101 = 1,
        F110 = 2,
        F112 = 3,
        F153 = 4,
        F154 = 5,
        F155 = 6,
        F156 = 7,
        F301 = 8,
        F302 = 9,
        F303 = 10,
        F304 = 11,
        F305 = 12,
        F306 = 13,
        F307 = 14,
        F308 = 15,
        F309 = 16,
        F310 = 17,
        F311 = 18,
        F319 = 19,
    }
```

I already fix it on number. But I don't need to fix it. I need to use enum as parameter. Can I use like this?

```
    public enum SCode
    {
        cmd = code,
    }
```

**code** is the variable that can be change anytime.
Thanks for answer and make me clear.

Comment: see this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955462/pass-in-an-enum-as-a-method-parameter]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide variables to your enumerations. They have to have a static value. You can provide something like this:

```
public enum SCode
{
    F100, -- its value will be 0
    F200  -- its value will be 1
}
```

or

```
public enum SCode
{
    F100 = 14, -- its value will be 14
    F200       -- its value will be 15
}
```

but you cannot provide a variable like this:

```
var employeeID = 14;
public enum SCode
{
    F100 = employeeID, -- won't work
    F200
}
```

Comment: On your first example, F100 will be 0, not 1. The default is to start from 0.

Comment: Yes, so true. Thank you, @victor

Comment: Thanks, So, If I want to use dynamic value, then I should not use enum, right?

Comment: @SomCtk did you find this answer useful? If you did, please feel free to mark it answered to bring closure to your question or feel free to wait for other answers also.

Comment: @zedfoxus Yeah, I found solution. I didn't use Enum anymore for this project. cuz I have n't to fix the value. I just use normal parameter to store it.