# Passing enum to function is not working

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I am trying to pass enum to my method and this is how I am trying:

```
public enum Pizza
    {
        [Description("Peeporoni")]
        Peeporoni = 1,
        [Description("Maxican")]
        Maxican = 1,
       [Description("Cheese")]
        Cheese = 2
    }

public static string GetType(Pizza pizza)
        {
            switch (pizza)
            {
                case pizza.:   //not getting any thing
                    return pizza.;

                case pizza.:
                    return pizza.
            }
        }
```

Now I would like to call GetType method and pass specific type of pizza to this method:

```
GetType(Pizza.Peeporoni);  //should return Pepporoni
GetType(Pizza.Maxican);  //should return Maxican
```

I have tried like this too from below [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955462/pass-in-an-enum-as-a-method-parameter) but still it's not working:

```
public static string GetType(Enum pizza)
        {
            switch (pizza)
            {
                case pizza.:   //not getting any thing
                    return pizza.;

                case pizza.:
                    return pizza.
            }
        }
```

### Update

I am doing like this but I don't want to do this because I am calling GetType method from lots of place so if any change would be made in a pizza name then I have to find and change at every place:

```
public static string GetType(string pizza)
        {
            switch (pizza)
            {
                case "Peeporoni":   //not getting any thing
                    return "Peeporoni";

                case "Cheese":
                    return "Cheese";
            }
        }

GetType("Peeporoni");  //return Pepporoni
GetType("Cheese");  //return Maxican
```

### Goal

My goal is to create this process in such a way that if some day any change will come in name of pizza like **Peeporoni becomes Pepparoniz**  then I will have to just change it at one place only.

Comment: Enum does not contain `type`, it just contains some static numbers. so when you pass `Pizza.Peeporoni` you already have that `Peeporoni`. not sure what you are trying to get.

Comment: `pizza` is the name of the parameter object. `Pizza` is the name of the enum type. Keep in mind that C# is a case-sensitive language.

Comment: Write `case Pizza.Peeporoni:` and `case Pizza.Maxican`, etc. C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Abion47 : I have updated my question for further details

Comment: I have provided everything that i have tried then why this downvote.Downvoter please tell me what is wrong in my question.

Comment: Be aware this is bad coding, write interface IPizza and all other pizzas(Peperoni and so on) should inherit it. What if you have 30 different pizzas.

Comment: @mybirthname : Sorry i was not knowing that is why i have ask question here so that i can learn to do this in better way but i dont know why i got downvote

Comment: I don't understand your question (although I'm not downvoter)... but hey you pass `"Peeporoni"` and you get `"Peeporoni"` again.... so what that means?? is that really your case? if you want to work with types and objects make use of classes. read tutorials about that

Comment: @PeterDuniho i have include more details in my question like what i am currently doing

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary : I am passing type of pizza and i have some operation to do in my switch case which perform some operation on type of pizza that is passed and return some string value but i havent shown that part because it was not important

Comment: ok. so use _un-lucky's_ answer. if you want to change a name just right click on one of them and click Rename. it will automatically rename all those variables you need.

Comment: I recommend you install Resharper tool for .net. it provides many options. including renaming a word through all your project. it shows which ones you want to rename and you just tick them. very easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I explain this is bad coding, you should have separate objects for every pizza. This objects should implement common interface.

```
public interface IPizza
{
    //just example method
    public int Price();
    public string Name{ get; set; };
}

public class Peperoni: IPizza
{
    private string _name = "Peperoni Pizza";
    public int Price()
    {
         return 10;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name;}
        set { _name=value;}
    }
}

public class Cheese: IPizza
{
    private string _name = "Cheese Pizza";

    public int Price()
    {
         return 8;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name;}
        set { _name=value;}
    }
}

// and so on
```

When the user wants peperoni

```
 IPizza peperoniPizza = new Peperoni();
 Console.WriteLine(peperoniPizza.Name);
```

This give you a flexibility if the user want peperoni withou salam

```
 IPizza peperoniPizzaNoSalami = new Peperoni();
 peperoniPizzaNoSalami.Name = "Peperoni pizza without salam";
```

Also for an example if you have class `DeliveryComapny` and they have method IsPizzaDelivered. You can reuse every pizza in this class.

```
 public void IsPizzaDelivered(IPizza pizza)
 {
      //you should have IsDelivered property in IPizza for this
      //after some actions here you set it to true or false.

      //you can take the dependencyof the IPizza in the constructor of your Delivery company too.
 }
```

Comment: +1 for cleaner code. I doubt that changing the name to "... without salami" will change the ingredients (maybe you want an `PreparationInstructions` field), but anyway, this is the right direction.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I agree  for sure this should be extended.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and i really appreciate it and sorry to bother you again but i have included my goal in my question.Would you like to say something for that??

Comment: @Learning If you take my approach, you need to change only the default _name for the pepperoni to something else.

Comment: Can you please help me with this linq query:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288901/linq-query-giving-me-inappropriate-output-while-counting-inner-child-elements

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the select case that you ware used in the code, you have to specify the enum types in the case, or if you are comparing with string then you have to give `switch (pizza.ToString())`

I hope you are tried to achieve the following:

```
public static string GetType(Pizza pizza)
{
    switch (pizza)
    {
        case Pizza.Peeporoni:
            return Pizza.Peeporoni.ToString();
        case Pizza.Maxican:
            return Pizza.Maxican.ToString();
        case Pizza.Cheese:
            return Pizza.Cheese.ToString();    
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

So when you call this method like the following :

```
Pizza pizza =Pizza.Cheese;
string pizaType = GetType(pizza);
```

you will get `pizaType="Cheese"`

If you are looking for a method which will accept string and return corresponding pizza type means you can modify the method signature like the following:

```
public static Pizza GetType(string pizza)
{
    switch (pizza)
    {
        case "Peeporoni":
            return Pizza.Peeporoni;
        case "Cheese":
            return Pizza.Cheese;
        default:
            return Pizza.Maxican;
    }
}
```

Now you can call this method like the this:

```
 Pizza pizza = GetType("Peeporoni"); // which will give you the type as `Pizza.Peeporoni`
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid passing this hardcoded pizza type that is why i am trying to pass enum because in case if there will be any change in name of pizza or anything then this would lead to change every where in my code.Isnt it possible to create something like changing at 1 place and it doesnt requires changing at all place

Comment: @Learning So what is it that you are actually trying to accomplish with this code? Because from the sound of it you are trying to pass in an enum value and return... the exact same enum value? Or a string representation of the value? Or take a string and return an enum value? What is your end goal?

Comment: @Abion47 I would like to pass specific enum type of my method and based on type of enum that is passed i am doing some processing and return some string value but my concern is i want to make this process generic so that if some day any change(like change in spelling name of pizza or anything) comes then changing will require at only 1 place.This is my goal